# how can i check the imported data in mixpanel after usnig import api

Tags: api, import, mixpanel

I am new to mixpanel and I'm trying to import the people profile from one mixpanel project to another project. for I porting the user I have used below mentioned mixpanel API to import people profile.

```
"curl https://api.mixpanel.com/import \
-u YOUR_API_SECRET: \
-d data= somedata \
```